# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installer support for fake RAID 1

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows-7, raid

I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS alongside Windows 7. Should not be a big problem, but it just occurred to me that I am using a software RAID to mirror my disks (RAID 1). 
Now there is some information on about that, but most of it is pretty old by now. It basically says that I have to boot into the live system and install dmraid. Afterwards I have to configure a whole bunch of stuff (I did not understand it really). Pretty complicated. On the other hand someone mentioned (can't find the source anymore though) that the installer of newer versions of Ubuntu should recognize that I have fake RAID set up and handle that automatically. Is that true? Does the information I have found in the [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto) still apply to 12.04? What things do I have to consider during the installation process?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why the downvote? I did research the topic but just could not follow the explanations. And the link I posted to the Ubuntu documentation only covers 10.04 and older versions thus the question whether the information is still valid for 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you think you could do and it has nothing to do with Windows or Linux if you plan to dual boot.  Something has to control the RAID1 in your case before either OS boots (Win or Linux).  The only case where it would work as described, you would need to have a smart controller where the RAID is handled by the disk controller and not by either OS.